# Async Task to Java equivalent

Tags: java, android, sql

I did something in android a year ago and was wondering if it was possible to convert it into java.

Code from android:

```
private void search() {
    class GetUsers extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
        ProgressDialog loading;

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... v) {
            HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put(Config.Key_Search, Search);
            RequestHandler rh = new RequestHandler();
            String res = rh.SendPostRequest(Config.URL_Search, params);
            Log.d("AAAA", "doInBackground: " + res);
            return res;
        }

        /**
         * After the response is given from the database
         * @param s json String
         */
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            loading.dismiss();
            showResult(s);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            loading = ProgressDialog.show(SearchActivity.this, "Searching", "Wait a sec", false, false);
        }
    }
    GetUsers getUsers = new GetUsers();
    getUsers.execute();
}
```

Its to search a SQL database given the parameter Search.

Any answers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

```
import java.util.concurrent.*;

ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
Callable<String> task = new Callable<>() {
    public String call() {
        System.out.println("Before sleep");
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(10);
        System.out.println("After sleep");
        return "foo";
    }
}
Future<String> future = executor.submit(task);
TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);
System.out.println("Do some stuff in parallel");
String result = future.get();
```

Comment: @lanc-java I have a similar use case, trying to convert AsyncTasks to ExecutorService to return a List from a Room database.  Another answer suggests using submit() on ExecutorService and get() on the Dao method (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52242933/room-database-query).  Would appreciate your thoughts on that approach versus your approach using a Callable and a Future.