# Room Database Query

Tags: java, android, android-room

I'm new to `Room` and i'm trying to `query` my `database` to get a `row` from it. I attempted doing so by `querying` it with the `primary key` which is id but the problem is i don't know how to return the target `object` from the `repository`.

This is the `Dao`

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM targets WHERE id = :id LIMIT 1")
Targets findTargetById(int id);
```

THis is the Repository class

```
 public Targets findTarget (int id) {
    new findTargetByIDAsyncTask(mTargetsDao).execute(id);

}

   private static class findTargetByIDAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Targets> {

    private TargetsDao mAsyncTaskDao;

    findTargetByIDAsyncTask(TargetsDao dao) {
        mAsyncTaskDao = dao;
    }


    @Override
    protected Targets doInBackground(Integer... integers) {

        return mAsyncTaskDao.findTargetById(integers[0]);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Targets targets) {
        super.onPostExecute(targets);
    }
}
```

Comment: you can do anything you want with your targets in the onPostExecute methode of your repository. if you want to use it anywhere out of your assyncTask then you can create a global variable and affect the value in onPostExecute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two ways to return a result.

The first way is to call `AsyncTask.get()` method, but it will still hold a MainThread what leads to ANR if a task will longer than 5 seconds:

```
public Targets findTarget (int id) {
    return new findTargetByIDAsyncTask(mTargetsDao).execute(id).get();
}
```

The second way is more complicated but it will not hold the MainThread. You should add a Callback class:

```
public interface Callback {
        void onSuccess(Targets targets);
    }
```

Each method of your repository will look like that:

```
public void findTarget (Callback callback, int id) {
        new findTargetByIDAsyncTask(mTargetsDao, callback).execute(id);
    }
```

And AsynTask will look like that:

```
private static class FindTargetByIDAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Targets> {

    private final TargetsDao mAsyncTaskDao;
    private final Callback callback;

    FindTargetByIDAsyncTask(TargetsDao dao, Callback callback) {
        mAsyncTaskDao = dao;
        this.callback = callback;
    }


    @Override
    protected Targets doInBackground(Integer... integers) {
        return mAsyncTaskDao.findTargetById(integers[0]);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Targets targets) {
        callback.onSuccess(targets);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The point is to get the data/object from a background thread. You can use Android's `AsyncTask` or a `ExecutorService`. A simple example is if you want to get a String of a user name the method will be:

```
private String getName() {
    String name = null;
    try {
        name = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().submit(() ->
                userDao.fetchUserName()).get();
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return name;
}
```

Comment: I have a similar use case.  Your answer appears simple and efficient.  But I see a lot of answers that use a Callable and a Future to return an object (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40658145/async-task-to-java-equivalent).  Would appreciate your thoughts on your approach versus the Callable/Future approach.